# Recover centos 7 machine running zfs

Tags: centos, zfs

I have a centos 7 machine using a zfs dataset as the boot volume.  I entered single user mode to reset the root password using the steps in [this guide](https://www.unixmen.com/reset-root-password-centos-7/). I triple checked that I remembered to `touch /.autorelabel` from my console history.

I had followed the same steps on two other machines successfully but on this machine when I rebooted the system it gives the error `error: checksum verification failed.` and enters a grub rescue prompt.

I found [this forum thread](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/grub-rescue-checksum-verification-failed.39143/) where someone appears to have had pretty much the same issue and resolved it by booting a livecd and doing a `zpool import` followed by a `zpool scrub`, but I've been unable to get a livecd to boot.  During the boot process it keeps failing when trying to start the login service.  I've tried two different centos 7 livecd images.  Does anyone have any suggestions for recovering from this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centos 7 live cds weren't working for me but I was able to boot using a system rescue cd with zfs support I found [here](https://github.com/nchevsky/systemrescuecd-zfs?fbclid=IwAR0p24DJPvrwzrC_4902kJa_aCH_mcYlQIRGYWbPJQbmd-5soj_bJ1YnH3c).  Once booted to a shell I was able to execute:

```
zpool import -f rpool
```

followed by:

```
zpool export
```

Then I rebooted the machine and it booted from the local drive normally.